# Preventing Hyperlink inside WPF RichTextbox from being edited by end user

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am having a WPf hyperlink inside a WPf Richtextbox , clicking on hyperlink results in opening of  a popup.
But i wish to prevent the editing of hyperlink text.

Initially it looks like below

[image]

but when user edits the hyperlink it looks like this

[image]

So I wish to prevent this editing of hyerlink.

Answer (score 1):

If you add in a container it cannot be edited (but removed as a whole):

```
<InlineUIContainer>
    <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com/">
            <Run Text="Google"/>
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</InlineUIContainer>
```

Would this be any good?

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: It's not like this cannot easily be translated to C#